# refresh() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm currently working on a django project that uses Haystack/elasticsearch.

I've had much trouble installing elasticsearch on windows, finally using this setup: http://ruilopes.com/elasticsearch-setup/

With a bit of tweaking for the elasticsearch.bat it finally worked after running the bat file.

Now I'm trying to register a user on the website which gives me this error:

> refresh() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

in this line:

```
x:\development\xxxx\xxxx\src\django-haystack\haystack\backends\elasticsearch_backend.py in update

    174.self.conn.refresh(index=self.index_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error until I upgraded pyelasticsearch.  These two versions worked together:

- django_haystack-2.1.0
- pyelasticsearch-0.6.1